# Results about existence/uniqueness of solution to Euler-Lagrange equations?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, calculus-of-variations

While studying calculus of variations, there is one question that I feel is missing in the texts I'm reading:

What can we say about the existence and/or uniqueness of solutions to Euler-Lagrange equations? Is there any general result?

I tried to google it, but found nothing.

Comment: At the level of generality of your question, the answer is that existence holds for some problems and not for others and uniqueness holds for some problems and not for others.  Do you have some specific situation in mind?  A good general source that discusses existence and uniqueness in various different problems is the 2-volume work of Hildebrandt and Giaquinta, "The Calculus of Variations".

Comment: No, I had no particular situation in mind; just wondering whether the existence of a lagrangian could give some help in order to solve the equations. And thank you for the reference; I'll take a look to it.

Comment: I would add that the situation is much easier if you are optimizing over functions of a single real variable than if there are more than one independent variable. There are numerous classical texts covering the first case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The  so called   direct method of the  calculus of variations provides one such existence and uniqueness result.

Here is the gist of it.  Suppose that  $X$ is a reflexive  Banach space, e.g.   a Hilbert space or a space of the form $L^p(\Omega)$, $p\in (1,\infty)$, $\Omega$ open subset of some Euclidean space.    We are given a   functional  $J$ on $X$, i.e., a function

$$ J : X\to (-\infty, \infty]$$

and we seek  minimizers of such functionals, i.e.,  points $x_0\in X$ such that

$$J(x_0)=\inf_{x\in X} J(x)$$

The  subset  of $X$ where $J$ is finite is called  the  domain of  $J$.  It is typically described by various equalities and inequalities called constraints.

**Existence Theorem.** *Suppose that $J$ satisfies the following conditions.*

\begin{equation}
\inf_{x\in X} J(x)>-\infty.
\tag{A}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \mbox{The set}\;\;\lbrace
J\leq t\rbrace:=\lbrace x\in X;\;\; J(x)\leq t\rbrace
\;\; \mbox{is convex},\;\;\forall t\in \mathbb{R}.
\tag{B}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \mbox{The set}\;\;\lbrace
J\leq t\rbrace\;\; \mbox{is closed in the norm topology},\;\;\forall t\in \mathbb{R}.
\tag{C}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\|x\|\to\infty} J(x)=\infty.
\tag{D}
\end{equation}

*Then   $J$ admits at least one minimizer.*

**Remark.** I should comment on the   four conditions above. Condition (A)  states that $J$ is bounded from below. Condition (B) states that $J$ is a convex function in the usual way.   Condition (C) states that $J$  is lower semicontinuous in the norm    topology. Under the convexity  assumption this is equivalent to $J$ being lower semicontinuous with respect to the  weak topology.  If $J$ happens to be differentiable, then  the differential of $J$ at any minimizer $x_0$ is zero. The ensuing equation $dJ(x_0)=0$   translates into the classical Euler-Lagrange equations.  The minimizer postulated by the above theorem is **unique** provided that  $J$ is **strictly convex**. For more about the direct method see  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_method_in_the_calculus_of_variations)  and the reference therein.

In general, the objects satisfying the Euler-Lagrange equations are critical points of a functional $J: X\to\mathbb{R}$, i.e., points where the differential of $J$ vanishes.      The critical points  that are observable and  detectable  in the real world are stable and these correspond to (local) minimizers of $J$. Sometime, one is interested in   not necessarily stable  objects, i.e., critical points of $J$  that are not necessarily   local minimizers.  Morse theory  is particularly good at detecting    such points.   All applications  of this theory  are based on the following principle.

Suppose that $J: H\to\mathbb{R}$ is a $C^2$ function on a Hilbert space $H$ satisfying some additional compactness assumption (e.g. the Palais-Smale condition).   Suppose that there exist real numbers  $a < b$ such that the sublevel sets

$$ \lbrace J\leq a\rbrace\;\;\mbox{and}\;\; \lbrace J\leq b\rbrace$$

are not homeomorphic. Then  $J$ admits a  critical point $x_0$ such that

$$ J(x_0)\in [a,b]. $$

For more detail see  the booklet by Paul Rabinowitz, *Minimax methods in critical point theory with applications to differential equations.*

Comment: Minor point, (B) means that $J$ is quasi convex, not necessarily convex.